# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: java, gson

У меня есть JSON вот такого формата.

```
   "data":{
      "company":{
         "id":3320951,
         "name":"yGsPblxjrEQKelRqyctrTctcFevweN",
         "status":0,
         "user":{
            "id":21951447,
            "first_name":"ZiLiJYkqmcKzGxcdVJuGgOmEMglWmv",
            "last_name":"XXUjMzLMKIkByQFLguOXIDdzYJHJYA",
            "middle_name":"zxeevoHSCaDahdDUApGtmgetEMvEJK"
         },
         "products":[
            [
               [
                  [
                     {
                        "id":1143937701,
                        "name":"Auto test 1",
                        "description":"value",
                        "price":100,
                        "price_currency":"UAH"
                     }
                  ],
                  [
                     {
                        "id":1143937701,
                        "name":"Auto test 1",
                        "description":"value",
                        "price":100,
                        "price_currency":"UAH"
                     }
                  ]
               ],
               [
                  {
                     "id":1143937701,
                     "name":"Auto test 1",
                     "description":"value",
                     "price":100,
                     "price_currency":"UAH"
                  }
               ]
            ],
            [
               {
                  "id":1143937701,
                  "name":"Auto test 1",
                  "description":"value",
                  "price":100,
                  "price_currency":"UAH"
               }
            ]
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Сервер одтает поле products как масив масивов в масиве масивов)

При попытке распарсить это все через gson получаю следующую ошибулину

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3781 path $.products[0][1][0]
```

Для парсинга есть POJO класс Company где следующее поле products обьявлено след. образом

```
 @SerializedName("products")
 @Expose
 private List<List<List<List<Product>>>> products = null;
```

Comment: У вас разное число вложений. Т.е. в одном в первом элементе массива должен быть `List<List<List<Product>>>`, а в следующем `List<List<Product>>`